# Publishing Web from Visual Studio

Tags: c#, jquery, sql, visual-studio-2012, publish

I am trying to publish a web api from visual studio that has been previously done successfully.

The solution contains 2 projects:

-TheInventoryDataAccessLayer <-----Class Library

-InventoryIngenium <-----The WebSite

I right click on inventory ingenium and hit publish, I publish it using the same profile that the company has been using to update it to the server (using file system publish method to a T:/ drive) and I believe it upload correctly as most of the site works however some pages result in Errors WHERE AS when I run it locally (from visual studio) it all works just fine. I was wondering where this problem is coming from? did I not publish properly? or does the published version simply have errors I do not encounter locally?...

The error when I navigate to an invalid page on the published version is...

GET http://(IP here)/Part_Cost 500 (Internal Server Error)
Navigated to http://(IP Here) :84/Part_Cost

any insight you can provide me is much appreciated, the whole company cannot use the api anymore since I tried publishing the new version!

Comment: Have you verified you dont have a write issue on the T drive? Does it work if you publish to another folder and copy manually to T? Can you manually delete all files in the publish folder and try again?

Comment: I believe all that works, I think I am not publishing the database? that might be the issue but I dont know how...